# What is a reliable way to open the Gallery?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-gallery

The following code works most of the time:

```
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("content://media/internal/images/media"));
startActivity(intent);
```

It throws the following exception sometimes (reported by error log from users):

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent {
>   act=android.intent.action.VIEW
>   dat=content://media/internal/images/media }

Stack trace:

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle
>   Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW
>   dat=content://media/internal/images/media }   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1899)
>     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1589)
>     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4228)
>     at android.support.v4.app.k.startActivityForResult(SourceFile:50)   at
>   android.support.v4.app.p.startActivityForResult(SourceFile:79)    at
>   android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4187)   at
>   android.support.v4.app.p.startActivityForResult(SourceFile:859)   at
>   android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4515)    at
>   android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4483)

I am wondering if some users' Android devices do not have Gallery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am wondering if some users' Android devices do not have Gallery.

There is no requirement for any Android device to have any exported activity that supports that particular `Intent` structure (`ACTION_VIEW` for whatever MIME type is tied to that `Uri`, plus a `content` scheme).

Beyond that, there is no single app named "Gallery". Out of ~2 billion devices and ~10,000 device models, there may be hundreds of apps that serve this general role, and a device might not have any such app.

> What is a reliable way to open Gallery on Android?

[See `CATEGORY_APP_GALLERY`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_APP_GALLERY), and be sure to handle the case where there is no matching activity.

Comment: Thanks for the elucidation.  On all of our testing Android devices and Android emulators, Gallery is one of the items on the Applications page. Isn't it an app?

Comment: @Hong: There are lots of apps named "Gallery". I would imagine that there are 100+ apps that qualify as a "gallery" that come pre-installed on those ~10,000 device models.

Comment: @Hong: More importantly, your code has little to do with a gallery. You are seeking an activity that can view a particular collection of content from a provider. I can easily write an app named "This is Not a Gallery" that offers an activity that responds to that `Intent` structure. The functionality that I provide may have nothing to do with what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the further clarification.